# How to clone a folder on a PC on Github

Tags: git

I'm new to git. I'm finding it hard to figure out how (if possible) can I copy a folder (along with its sub-folders) over to a git repository either using the bash or the web interface while maintaining the folder structure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you should clone your repository to xxx-subfolder:

```
git clone <repository-URL> xxx
```

Now you copy your folder to `xxx` folder.

Add the folder to git repository:

```
git add .
```

Commit the change:

```
git commit -m "New folder is added"
```

Push the change to remote git server:

```
git push
```

Comment: Thanks for the easy-to-follow step-wise answer.

Answer (score 0):

In the future try to elaborate your question with clear goals and problems that you encountered.

- If you want to have your local project as git repository on GitHub then follow https://help.github.com/articles/adding-an-existing-project-to-github-using-the-command-line/
- If you want to add some folder to your existing GitHub repository then clone it to your computer, copy-paste folder into it (on desirable place in structure) , commit and push to GitHub remote.